# How to run a program in admin mode from the command prompt?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, command-line, admin

From the regular command prompt (not powershell), I want to run a program that requires admin mode. Since the program is long running, the window must remain open. The program requires command line switches and arguments.

I haven't seen any other post that has all of these requirements.

I stumbled upon a solution but don't understand why the argument passing works. Can someone explain? Is there a more powershell like way of doing the same? A bonus would be to add the ability for making a first-use password prompt and saves the password thereafter.

Comment: I edited to explain that the command must work within the normal command prompt, not powershell, and be batch file friendly.

Comment: Also I don't believe TestComplete's answer will accept switches and arguments. Or at least I don't know how, hence this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following single line, batch file friendly, command will open an elevated command window, execute the command (with any switches and arguments), and keep the elevated window open.

```
powershell.exe -Command start-process -verb runas cmd {/K "myprog.py -v all"}
```

Comment: This looks like a useful answer - perhaps you could repost it as an answer to the duplicate?